# Installing/using p5py/p5 under Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, p5py

I have coded some projects in [processing](https://www.processing.org/) that I would like to continue in python under the python port [p5py/p5](https://github.com/p5py/p5).

I am using Anaconda as my Python environment, but couldn't find a way of installing p5py/p5 via conda; installing p5py/p5 via pip works, but the library can't be imported into within Spyder in the Anaconda environment.
I have been able to install all libraries on which p5py/p5 depends from within Anaconda, which makes it a bit frustrating that I can't get p5 installed.

I would therefore appreciate any tips for making p5py/p5 importable from with the Anaconda environment.
As performance is currently not a pressing issue to me so suboptimal workarounds would also be of help.

Comment: Spyder should pickup all installed packages regardless... Are you sure your pip is the one inside your anaconda environment?  I would think fixing that is easier....

Comment: "conda install pip" and then "pip install p5 --user" solved the issue.